# CountMatches() equivalent Postgres query

Tags: java, postgresql, string-utils

We know the stringutils function CountMatches() - CountMatches - counts the number of occurrences of one String in another. I need an equivalent query in postgresql to count the number of occurence of a string in another.

Any idea would appreciated

Comment: So, which of the string matching functions listed in the extensive official manuals did you consider and why didn't they meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp_matches with *greedy* switch:

```
select count ( * )
from regexp_matches ( 'abc abc', 'ab', 'g' ); -- result is 2
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [`regexp_matches()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html)

The solution with `regexp_matches()` that @Igor suggested and [@Tomasz implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25582213/939860) is short and elegant, but has two downsides:

- Regular expressions are powerful, but generally much slower than simple functions.
- The aggregate step makes it non-trivial to integrate into bigger queries.

To use it in a query with multiple source rows:

```
SELECT t.*, count(match) AS ct
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL regexp_matches(t.string, 'ab', 'g') match ON TRUE
GROUP  BY t.tbl_id
ORDER  BY t.tbl_id;
```

Or:

```
SELECT t.*, m.ct
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS ct
   FROM   regexp_matches(t.string, 'ab', 'g')
   ) m ON TRUE
ORDER  BY t.tbl_id;
```

#### [`replace()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) / [`length()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html)

The expression is not as elegant, but should be faster and can be used on sets more easily:

```
SELECT (length(col) - length(replace(col, 'match', ''))) / length('match') AS ct;
```

You can wrap this in a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_count_matches(_string text, _match text)
  RETURNS int LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$$
SELECT (length(_string) - length(replace(_string, _match, ''))) / length(_match)
$$;
```

Then:

```
SELECT f_count_matches('abc cab,xabx abab', 'ab');
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4242c/6) demonstrating all.

Comment: I've tested your function on a large text (8630640 characters long 'Lorem ipsum [...]', counting 'Lorem'). It usually took about 200 ms. Version using regular expressions function took 45 sec. (There was no difference in performance on small input). Upvoting. Definitely.

Comment: @TomaszSiorek: Thanks for the benchmark. Always good to see actual results.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not have that function, but you can work around it this way:

```
SELECT array_length(regexp_split_to_array('axbxcxdxexfxg','b'),1)-1;  -- returns 1
SELECT array_length(regexp_split_to_array('axbxcxdxexfxg','x'),1)-1;  -- returns 6
SELECT array_length(regexp_split_to_array('axbxcxdxexfxg','z'),1)-1;  -- returns 0
```

There may be edge cases that do not work correctly.

`regexp_split_to_array` creates an array with the non-matching parts. The number of elements in the array is one more than the number of matches (at least for normal cases). So, `array_length` and `-1` produce the count of matches.

```
CREATE FUNCTION num_matches(string text,pattern text)
RETURNS int AS $$
    SELECT array_length(regexp_split_to_array(string,pattern),1)-1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Comment: It may be easier to count the number of rows, outputted by `regexp_matches`.